# snakemake define folder as output

Tags: snakemake

I try to run prokka using snakemake and rule all. In the latter I define all output folders which will be produced by prokka to write the results. Prokka requires a folder to be supplied as an output rather than a file.

A simplified version of what I have is here:

```
PATIENTID_ls = range(2)
rule all:
input:
    expand("results_{subjectID}_outputfolder",subjectID=PATIENTID_ls), 

rule prokka:
    input:
        "contigs/subject_{subjectID}/contigs.fasta",
    output:
        "results/subject_{subjectID}_outputfolder",
    shell:
        "prokka --cpus 1 --proteins ../GCF_000009645.1_ASM964v1_genomic.gbff --outdir {output} --prefix contigs500_anno9ref {input} "
```

When running:

```
$snakemake -p
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in line 2 of Snakefile:
Missing input files for rule all:
results_1_outputfolder
results_0_outputfolder
```

It works however when specifying the output explicitly:

```
snakemake -p results/subject_1_outputfolder
```

I am sure that is noob mistake on my side, but after hours of playing around I could not solve the issue. Help is highly appreciated. 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example has some issues as your `rule all` output files do not match your `rule prokka` output file.

However, one way to implement what you want to do is to use `params` to specify the output directory and use that as argument to the flag `--outdir {params.outdir}`.

A similar example is shown below:

```
PATIENTID_ls = [1,2]
PREFIX = "contigs500_anno9ref"

rule all:
    input:
        expand("results_{subjectID}_outputfolder/{prefix}.gff",subjectID=PATIENTID_ls, prefix=PREFIX), 

rule prokka:
    input:
        "contigs/contigs.fasta",
    params:
        outdir= "results_{subjectID}_outputfolder",
        prefix= PREFIX,
    output:
        "results_{subjectID}_outputfolder/{prefix}.gff",
    shell:
        "echo '{params.prefix}' > {params.outdir}/{PREFIX}.gff"
```

You still should specify a file as an output in `rule prokka` and in `rule all`.  Based on the example on the prokka [repo](https://github.com/tseemann/prokka) the output file is essentially `{outdir}/{prefix}.gff`.  You can specify that as the output to both `rule all` and `rule prokka` without ever directly using it while invoking the command.

---

Alternatively even though there does not seem to be a reason for it, you could use a mock file to signify completion of the rule.

An example would be:

```
PATIENTID_ls = [1,2]
rule all:
    input:
        expand("results_{subjectID}_outputfolder/mockfile.txt",subjectID=PATIENTID_ls), 

rule prokka:
    input:
        "contigs/contigs.fasta",
    params:
        outdir= "results_{subjectID}_outputfolder",
        prefix= "contigs500_anno9ref",
    output:
        "results_{subjectID}_outputfolder/mockfile.txt",
    shell:
        "echo '{params.prefix}' && touch {params.outdir}/mockfile.txt"
```

Comment: Thx JohnnyBD...the params did the trick. I prefer the upper solution, as a mock output file lacks specificity if a run was truly successful.

Answer (score 2):

As @JohnnyBD mentioned, your major problem appears to be with `rule all` output not matching `rule prokka`. If you still need to use directory as `output` instead of a file, you may want to use [`directory()`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#directories-as-outputs) as it better handles edge cases.

Comment: Thx JeeYem! That indeed would have solved my problem too (and provides exactly what I was looking for). Thx also for the link to the documentation...I have missed it there.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a variable refering to your output directory, and call it on the rule:

```
outputdir= "your_output_directory"

rule Align_Sequences:
    input: sequence.fasta
    output: outputdir + "/sequence_aligned.fasta"
    shell: "mafft  {input} > {output}"
```

Comment: how do you declare the rule all? or you don't one?