# snakemake with prefix as output including a path

Tags: snakemake

How can I make sure in rule all that the output folder was well created?
Should I add each expected result file?

somehow relates to [snakemake define folder as output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53749519/snakemake-define-folder-as-output) but in my case the specified 'output' is a combination of a path to a dir and a prefix for all results files (they wil be multiple)

the following command creates a folder path Analysis/MosDepth and adds to that path the files:

```
 gt0.mosdepth.global.dist.txt
 gt0.mosdepth.region.dist.txt
 gt0.per-base.bed.gz
 gt0.per-base.bed.gz.csi
 gt0.regions.bed.gz
 gt0.regions.bed.gz.csi


rule MosDepth:
    input:
        bam = "Analysis/Minimap2/"+UnpackedRawFastq+".bam",
        bed = "ReferenceData/"+UnpackedGenomeGFF+"_exons.bed"
    output:
        pfx = "Analysis/MosDepth/gt0"
    threads: config["threads"]
    shell:
        "mosdepth -t {threads} -b {input.bed} {output.pfx} {input.bam}"
```

I currently have only one of the files in rule all:, is this enough or is there a better way to ensure that the mosdepth has run well and not redo it in a later re-run?

```
rule all:
  input:
    "Analysis/MosDepth/gt0.regions.bed.gz"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend sth like this:

```
mos_out = ['gt0.mosdepth.global.dist.txt', 'gt0.mosdepth.region.dist.txt', 'gt0.per-base.bed.gz', 'gt0.per-base.bed.gz.csi', 'gt0.regions.bed.gz', 'gt0.regions.bed.gz.csi']

rule MosDepth:
    input:
        bam = "Analysis/Minimap2/"+UnpackedRawFastq+".bam",
        bed = "ReferenceData/"+UnpackedGenomeGFF+"_exons.bed"
    output:
        expand("Analysis/MosDepth/{mos_out}", mos_out=mos_out) 
    params:
       pfx = "Analysis/MosDepth/gt0"
    threads: config["threads"]
    shell:
        "mosdepth -t {threads} -b {input.bed} {params.pfx} {input.bam}"
```

If one of the output files is not created by the rule, snakemake will remove all the output files for you, and throw an error.

Comment: after editing {output.pfx} to {params.pfx} the command fails as it does not find the outputs soon enough. My initial command did work though! I am lost!

Comment: Ok that is surprising. Does Snakefile says which one(s) are missing? Can you run the file with `-n --printshellcmds` and confirm that the output is generated when you run with these flags? Can it be that there is a latency in the filesystem? You can add `--latency-wait 15`, and then snakemake will wait 15 seconds before checking whether the output exists.

Comment: my apologies Maarten, my all: rule was guilty and looking for files which did not exist yet. I still have issues producing correct all: rules and would need a crash course on this ;-)

Comment: Happy to help. Most of the time I use expand for that (in the same way we did here).