# How can I change the logfile naming for the cluster scheduler in snakemake?

Tags: python, hpc, snakemake

I am running job on a PBS TORQUE cluster and want to customize my log scripts for rules [repeated for many files](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/project_info/faq.html#how-do-i-run-my-rule-on-all-files-of-a-certain-directory).

The default naming scheme is for each script for each rule `snakejob.{rulename}.{id}.sh.o26730731`, e.g. `snakejob.all.7.sh.o26730731`, where only the ending varies for different files (as they are executed one after another). This comes from the script snakemake creates for submission to the cluster.

I can specify a common log-directory to `qsub` using the `-e` or `-o` options.

I know that profiles exist or that one could use wildcards, something like (I have to test that):

```sh
snakemake --jobs 10 --cluster "qsub -o logs/{wildcards.file} -e logs/{wildcards.file}"
```

Alternatively the naming of the script temporarily saved by snakemake under `.snakemake/tmp<hash>` could be altered to achieve unique naming of logs per file.

I tried to set the log-directory in the rule, but this did not work when I specified a directory (missing `.log`):

```
rule target:
    input:
        # mockfile approach: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53751654/9684872
        # replace? https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#directories-as-outputs
        file = expand(os.path.join(config['DATADIR'], "{file}", "{file}.txt"), file=FILES)

rule execute:
    log: 
        #dir = os.path.join(config['DATADIR'], "{file}") # Building DAG is stuck in endless loop
        dir = os.path.join(config['DATADIR'], "{file}.log") # works
    params:
        logdir = os.path.join(config['DATADIR'], "{file}") #works
```

So what is your approach or what would you suggest how this could be solved best to have logs identified by the `{file}` wildcard?